# Python module search path problem

Tags: python, search, path, module

I am trying to work on a dev environment but am find problems in that python seems to be using modules from the site-packages directory. I want it to be using the modules from my dev directory.

sys.path returns a bunch of dirs, like this

```
['', '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages' etc
```

This is good, it's using the current directory as the first place of lookup (at least this is how I understand it to be).

Ok now if I create say a file called command.py in the current directory, things work as I would expect them.

```
>>> import commands
>>> commands.__file__
   'commands.pyc'
```

I then exit out of the python shell, and start another one. I then do this.

```
>>> import foo.bar.commands
```

Now, what I'm expecting it to do is go down from the current directory to ./foo/bar/ and get me the commands module from there. What I get though is this

```
>>> foo.bar.commands.__file__
    '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo/bar/commands.pyc'
```

Even though from my current directory there is a ./foo/bar/commands.py

Using imp.find_module() and imp.load_module() I can load the local module properly. Whats actually interesting (although I don't really know what it means) is the last line that is printed out in this sequence

```
>>> import foo.bar.commands
>>> foo.bar.commands.__file__
   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo/bar/commands.pyc'
>>> foo.bar.__file__
   '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo/bar/__int__.pyc'
>>> foo.__file__
    './foo/__init__.pyc'
```

So if it can find the foo/**init**.pyc in the local dir why can't it find the other files in the local dir?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have __inits__.py in your subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that there's a `foo` directory under your current directory, but you don't tell us whether `foo/__init__.py` exists (even possibly empty): if it doesn't, this tells Python that `foo` is **not** a package.  Similarly for `foo/bar/__init__.py` -- if that file doesn't exist, even if `foo/__init__.py` does, then `foo.bar` is not a package.

You can play around a little by placing `.pth` files and/or setting `__path__` explicitly in your packages, but the basic, simple rule is to just place an `__init__.py` in every directory that you want Python to recognize as a package.  The contents of that file are "the body" of the package itself, so if you `import foo` and `foo` is a directory with a `foo/__init__.py` file, then that's what you're importing (in any case, the package's body executes the first time you import anything from the package or any subpackage thereof).

If that is not the problem, it looks like some other import (or explicit sys.path manipulation) may be messing you up.  Running python with a `-v` flag makes imports highly visible, which can help.  Another good technique is to place an

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

just before the import that you think is misbehaving, and examining sys.path, sys.modules (and possibly other advanced structures such as import hooks) at that point - is there a sys.modules['foo'] already defined, for example?  Interactively trying the functions from standard library module `imp` that locate modules on your behalf given a path may also prove instructive.

Comment: Thanks for the insight of the best way to go about it. I still dont't know what the problem is, but I guess am path of investigation like you outlined is the best way to go about discovering the problem

Comment: @kalium, ok, tx, please do let us know how it proceeds (if you just solve it, a comment here will suffice, if not, maybe another question).

Answer (score 0):

What is foo doing in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages?
It sounds like you have created foo in your local directory but that is not necessarily the one you are importing.

Try getting rid of the foo/bar in site-packages

Make sure your directory structure looks like this

```
/foo/__init__.py  
    /bar/__init__.py
        /commands.py
```

Also, it is a good idea to not reuse python standard library names for your own modules -- can you call your commands.py something else?

Comment: No, see that's the whole point. Being able to have foo in my /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ but also being able to have foo in my local directory and run it from there. It's not a standard python library.