# Django fresh install - ImportError: No module named core -- doing django tutorials

Tags: django, django-admin, importerror

I am an intermediate python programmer,
and a newbie with Django.

On windows XP SP3:

- Installed python msi 2.7.3 -- Ok.
- Installed django: setup.py install -- Ok.

```
>>>import sys  
>>>print sys.path  
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

>>>import django  
>>>django.get_version()  
(1, 4, 3, 'final', 0)

>>>django.__path__  
['C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django']  

>>>django.__file__  
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.pyc'

>>>import site  
>>>print site.getsitepackages()  
['C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'] 

>>>print site.getusersitepackages()  
C:\Documents and Settings\Marc\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages

>>>from sysconfig import get_config_var  
>>>get_config_var('userbase')  
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Marc\\Application Data\\Python'

>>>from django.core import management  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "pyshell#27", line 1, in module  
    from django.core import management  
ImportError: No module named core
```

Is the userbase the problem ?

(I have about 50hrs invested in exploring all the posts but none
   of the things they suggest worked for me, hence this post.
   btw I tried all this on 2 seperate PCs).

**Update**, I read here : 
[Python module search path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523551/python-module-search-path-problem)

> simple rule is to just place an `__init__.py` in every directory that you
>   want Python to recognize as a package"

(thanks Alex)

I started putting a copy of `__init__.py` from `..\django` in every directory that holds a module that would not load, and what do you know, Django started to work.

I am sure this is not normal:

1. Doing `python setup.py install` make Django ready to go ?
2. It worked on my first attempt when I did the tuts a year ago
     with python 2.6 and Django 1.3, without patching up with `__init__.py`,
     v1.3 has no `__init__.py` in the directories either( core, utils, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal.

The error comes from missing **__*init*__**.py files.

It was caused by **WinZip** not extracting all **__*init*__**.py files !

Use **7zip !!** XoS